# Stream loudness normalization (ExoPlayer)

Tags: android, audio-streaming, exoplayer2.x, internet-radio, android-automotive

Is there any way to normalize loudness while audio streaming (**live**) via ExoPlayer? I have seen some [discussions](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4541) on ExoPlayer repository but nobody seems to have any solution.